# Python, If in input "a" there is letter from input "b" print True

Tags: python, if-statement, input

i have a code:

```
consonants = list["b", "c", "ć", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "w", "y", "z", "ż", "ź"]
for w in word1 or word2:
    word1 = word1.replace(consonants, "")
    word2 = word2.replace(consonants, "")
    print(word1 + " " + word2)//thats for test


if word1 in word2:
 print(...)
```

Word1 and Word2 is user input. For easier talk about my problem let's imagine that word1 = love and word2 = mate. Like we see we got one letter which is in this two string "e". Now i need to print some text like "True" or anything IF there is a letter from input word1 in input word2 like i writed before.

to sum up:
My question is how to do that if any letter in word1 matches letter in word2 print something

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over one word checking if each character might be in the other word.

```py
for w in word1:
    if w in word2:
        print(‘True’)
        break
```